# Which device has lowest power consumption?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, dc-dc-converter, power-consumption

In one of my project I need to scale down 12V dc to 8V. For this purpose I know that I can use,

1. Voltage divider using two resistors.
2. An opamp with +ve feedback
3. A dc-dc converter

I know that I didn't provide any rating for them. But if someone target the general pros and cons of each then which one of these is better to use,
considering power consumption is a major issue.

Comment: Please check your spelling ! What is the best solution depends on the context. You don't tell us where the 12 V is coming from nor where the 8 V is going to. So it is impossible to provide a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DC-DC converter is the only choice if efficiency is paramount.

Any linear regulator scheme (which, crudely, includes the divider) is essentially acting as a "smart resistor" (well, the divider is just a dumb resistor) that burns off excess voltage as heat. Something like an LM317 adjustable regulator is usually a better choice than an op amp for that purpose, but in any case power in is always considerably greater than power out, and the difference is blown off as heat.

In a DC-DC converter, DC power in is converted to high-frequency AC and transformed to high-frequency AC at a different voltage, which is then converted back to DC and regulated. There are still losses, but they can be considerably lower losses.

Comment: DC DC converters have numerous variants, it doesn't necessarily involve an inverter+transformer+rectifier (that would be a pretty clunky one, in fact). Buck converters for starters can simply be PWM-based regulators.

Comment: True, ASSUMING the 8V needs to power some circuit which requires a large current. But if the 8 V was going to power a circuit which requires 1 mA max, would this still be your answer ?

Comment: +1 FakeMoustache, switching DCDC converters are complex circuits and with complexity comes more quiescent current. If the load is very light a linear regulator might be more efficient. Moreover, take a look at the efficiency graph of a switching regulator and you'll see it drops for low loads (due to switching losses), especially if they are fixed frequency .